# How do you open .NPY files?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I open .NPY files in python so that I can read them?
I've been trying to run some code I've found but it outputs in .NPY files so I can't tell if its working.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you add the code you tried to your question?

Comment: `numpy.load` is the reader for files produced with `numpy.save`

Answer (score 10):

*.npy files are binary files to store numpy arrays. They are created with

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
np.save('data.npy', data)
```

And read in like

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('data.npy')
```

Answer (score 3):

Late reply but I  think `NPYViewer` is a tool that can help you, as it allows you to quickly visualize the contents of `.npy` files without having to write code. It also has options to visualize 2D .npy arrays as grayscale images as well as 3D point clouds.

Reference: https://github.com/csmailis/NPYViewer